# ROS msg get seqence number || pointer adress allways added

Tags: ros, subscribe, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I have a problem with ROS and messages especially.

```
void recievedGoals_callback(const boost::shared_ptr<nav_msgs::Path const>& msg)
      {
               std::cerr << "header seq   " << msg->header.seq << std::cerr;
       }
```

The return of this is something like "header seq   150x6297a8" and not the sequence-number i published (15)

Why? - Why is a pointer-adress added? How can I get rid of this adress?

The subscriber is:

```
ros::Subscriber sub_PathToGoal = n.subscribe<nav_msgs::Path>("/Exp/Goal", 1, boost::bind(recievedGoals_callback, _1), ros::VoidConstPtr(),ros::TransportHints().tcpNoDelay());
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54213/ros-msg-get-seqence-number-%7C%7C-pointer-adress-allways-added/) by [HanSolow](https://answers.ros.org/users/4116/hansolow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are outputting std::cerr as the last value. That is the pointer variable being added.

I guess you want std::endl instead.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HanSolow](https://answers.ros.org/users/4116/hansolow/) on 2013-02-05**:
*doh* you were absolutely right. That solved it. Thanks!